# SignIn issue with AWS Cognito

Tags: flutter, amazon-web-services, dart, amazon-cognito

I'm new with AWS and I'm facing some troubles with AWS Cognito... I was able the create a new user easly but I don't understand how the SignIn part works. 
Whether I type in a good or a bad password, the result is the same no exception and `res.isSignedIn = false`.
I missed something but I don't know what
Here is my code :

```
class AuthenticationPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const AuthenticationPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<AuthenticationPage> createState() => _AuthenticationPageState();
}

class _AuthenticationPageState extends State<AuthenticationPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: FlutterLogin(
          logo: const AssetImage('assets/images/logo.png'),
          onLogin: (LoginData data) => _onLogin(context, data),
          onRecoverPassword: (_) => Future.value(""),
          onSignup: (SignupData data) => _onSignUp(context, data),
          messages: LoginMessages(
            userHint: 'Email',
            passwordHint: 'Mot de passe',
            confirmPasswordHint: 'Confirmez mot de passe',
            loginButton: 'CONNEXION',
            signupButton: 'INSCRIPTION',
            forgotPasswordButton: 'Mot de passe oublié ?',
            recoverPasswordButton: 'HELP ME',
            goBackButton: 'Retour',
            confirmPasswordError: 'Les deux mots de passe ne correspondent pas',
            recoverPasswordSuccess: 'Password rescued successfully',
          ),
          theme: LoginTheme(
            switchAuthTextColor: Colors.orange,
            primaryColor: Colors.white,
            cardTheme: const CardTheme(
              shadowColor: Colors.yellow,
              surfaceTintColor: Colors.transparent,
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
            buttonTheme: const LoginButtonTheme(
              backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<String?> _onLogin(BuildContext context, LoginData data) async {
    try {
      //final result = await Amplify.Auth.signOut(
      //  options: const SignOutOptions(globalSignOut: true),
      //);
      //safePrint(result.toString());
      final res = await Amplify.Auth.signIn(
          username: data.name, password: data.password);
      safePrint(res.toString());
      return null;
    } on AuthException catch (e) {
      safePrint(e);
      if (e is UserNotFoundException) {
        return "Impossible de trouver un compte associé à cette adresse e-mail";
      }
      return e.message;
    }
  }
}
```

I saw this post : [AWS Cognito Accepting Any Password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52806460/aws-cognito-accepting-any-password), so I tried to uninstall the app and relaunch it, didn't work. And I try to add this piece of code :

```
//final result = await Amplify.Auth.signOut(
//  options: const SignOutOptions(globalSignOut: true),
//);
//safePrint(result.toString());
```

But it changes nothing...

Comment: Could you please organize your question? It is really hard to read and understand it.

Comment: Done, I was doing it when you add your comment... Sorry